# C# Print an array of strings in the reverse order

Tags: c#

so I have a problem where when I open my program and select 4 which is supposed to make it display all of the strings in the array but in reverse.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Homework3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int optionIntOne;
            int optionIntTwo;
            int i;
            int num = 0;
            decimal k;

            string[] names = {"Keyhan", "Adolf", "Niklas", "Jenny",
                "Elisa", "Rudolf", "Bengt", "Hassan", "Kajsa", "Maggan"};

            Console.WriteLine("Please Select an Option Below:\n1 - Find a student by Index \n" +
                "2 - Find student Index by name\n3 - Display all student names with their Index \n" +
                "4 - Display all the students in reverse order");

            string optionStringone = Console.ReadLine();

            bool isNumericOne = Int32.TryParse(optionStringone, out optionIntOne);

            Console.Clear();

            switch (optionIntOne)
            {

                case 1:

                    Console.WriteLine("***FIND Student by ID" + "\n" + "Please select a number between 0 - 9:");

                    string studentNumber = (Console.ReadLine());

                    bool isNumericTwo = Int32.TryParse(studentNumber, out optionIntTwo);

                    if (isNumericTwo == true && optionIntTwo < names.Length)

                        Console.WriteLine(names[optionIntTwo]);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");

                    break;

                case 2:

                    Console.WriteLine("*** FIND Student Index by Name \n Please Print one of the above names");

                    foreach (string name in names)
                        Console.WriteLine((name));

                    Console.WriteLine("\n");

                    string studentName = (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
                    //ToUpper så slipper loopen göra det på repeat
                    Console.Clear();

                    bool b = false;

                    if (decimal.TryParse(studentName, out k) || studentName == string.Empty)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter a Valid Name");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        for (i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (names[i].ToUpper() == studentName)
                            {
                                b = true;

                                Console.WriteLine(names[i] + " Has the index of " + i);

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (b == false)
                            Console.WriteLine("The Student does not Exist in the List");
                    }


                    break;

                case 3:

                    while (num < names.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(num + " - " + names[num]);
                        num++;
                    }
                    break;

                case 4:

                    while (num < names.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(names[num].Reverse());
                        num++;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a Valid Number");
                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

(option 3 but to print them in reverse order)

Visual Studio isnt giving me any errors but it outputs like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOgYw.png) instead of the reverse order of this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDEde.png)
Anyone know how to fix?/could point out the problem

Comment: Post your code and errors (with full tracebacks) as part of your question; not as images or links to external sites.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and provide a [mre] _as part of your question, not as an external link_, and [format it correctly](/help/formatting)

Comment: `for (int i = names.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { Console.WriteLine(names[i]); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = 0;
    string[] names = { "Alice", "Bob", "Charles", "Delilah" };

    while (num < names.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(names.Reverse().ElementAt(num));
        num++;
    }
    
    // Prints
    //
    // Delilah
    // Charles
    // Bob
    // Alice
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

As per the comments it is not optimal to call `Reverse()` in each loop. Instead, perform the `Reverse()` outside of the loop.

A better alternative might be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] names = { "Alice", "Bob", "Charles", "Delilah" };

    for (int num = names.Length - 1; num >= 0; num--)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(names[num]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Hey how does ElementAt() work? (works fine) Thanks!

Comment: You could also just do a for loop from names.Length-1 down to 0 instead of reversing the list.

Comment: @Someone123. `ElementAt` returns the element at a specified index in a sequence. In your case we first `Reverse()` the array and then ask for index 0 (`ElementAt(0))`, index 1  (`ElementAt(1))` etc.

Comment: @AlexP Ah okay, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Someone123 Next time you have a question like "How does <method> work" I would really encourage you to just read the documentation. This answers a lot of questions before they even need to be asked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

First of all this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(names[num].Reverse());
```

Is reversing the strings inside the list (so `names[0].Reverse()` would be `"nahyeK"`) because string is also a list (a list of chars). If you want to reverse the whole list you only write `names.Reverse();`
read more at: [Microsoft docs - Reverse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.reverse?view=netcore-3.1)

So the next step would be to print it out.
When you do `list.Reverse();` it will return `IEnumerable<TSource>` which you can use in a loop to get the names.

```
        string[] names = {"Keyhan", "Adolf", "Niklas", "Jenny",
            "Elisa", "Rudolf", "Bengt", "Hassan", "Kajsa", "Maggan"};

        IEnumerable<string> reversedList = names.Reverse();

        foreach(string name in reversedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
```

I usually use list.Reverse().ToList() so i get a "normal" list again because it's in my opinion easier to use/understand.

There is some options, the namespace [system.linq.enumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1) got some stuff for that:

[.ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netcore-3.1) - converts it to an Array.

[.ToList()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netcore-3.1) - converts it to a List

So the complete solution would be to keep the `.Reverse` outside the loop like this:

```
foreach(name in names.Reverse().ToList())
{
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Comment: Great that you adapted the advice. Most low quality answer do not get improved which makes us mad at the reviews. Welcome to Stack Overflow and keep up learning the system! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `ToList()` at all - the `IEnumerable` returned from `Reverse` works well in a `foreach` loop. Although you'd need to if you wanted to do it all in one line:  `names.Reverse().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`